# comparing objects and returning list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class definition that looks like this:

```
public class MyObjectModel
{
   public int ObjectID { get; set; }

   //for when the user's data is split in 2 fields
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   //for when the user's data is all in one field
   public string FirstLastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of these `MyObjectModel` and I want to sort them by name with a custom sort process because that involves checking if the data contains a `LastName` (in this case sort using the `LastName`) or just `FirstLastName` (in this case I'm going to break the string and sort on the second term, if there's one, or just the whole string if there's only one word.)

I'm not sure on two things:

1. should I use `IComparer` or `IComparable`?
2. Once it determines the order of the sort (I can do that), how do I make it so that the output of the method is a list of ints representing `ObjectID`.

Comment: Depending on the version of C# you're using, you can use Linq to sort it.

Comment: For the precision, I'm using c# 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq:

```
  List<MyObjectModel> objects = new List<MyObjectModel>();
  List<int> ids = objects.OrderBy(o => FunctionWhichReturnsNameForSort(o)).Select(o => o.ObjectID).ToList();
```

`FunctionWhichReturnsNameForSort` can be implemented in another class, or an extension, or as a member.

```
// should be in a static helper class
public static string NameForSort(this MyObjectModel obj)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.LastName)) return obj.LastName;

  return obj.FirstLastName.Split(... // your splitting logic goes here
}

var ids = objects.OrderBy(o => o.NameForSort()).Select(o => o.ObjectID).ToList();
```

Comment: What should the FunctionWhichReturnsNameForSort function return? Should it return -1, 0, 1 based on the comparison logic ?

Comment: It should return a name used for sorting. I will add an example.

Comment: Ok, thanks; I'm going to combine this with Holterman's answer!

Comment: Quick follow-up: if the NameSort function returns an empty string, how is this going to be sorted?

Comment: Try it :) I believe that internally it uses Comparer<T>.Default to compare the objects.

Comment: For the moment, I'm not sure my sample data has cases where there's no name at all:) I'll update the database to make sure this works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you really need this strange double solution then you will run into this and similar problems more often. As a more general solution, consider putting the business logic for names in a few read-only properties:

```
//for when the user's data is split in 2 fields
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

//for when the user's data is all in one field
public string FirstLastName { get; set; }

public string FullName
{
   get { ... }  // pick from LastName, FirstName, FirstLastName 
}

public string SortName
{
   get { ... }  // pick from LastName, FirstLastName 
}
```

> Once it determines the order of the sort (I can do that), how do I make it so that the output of the method is a list of ints representing ObjectID

```
result = MyObjectList
          .OrderBy(m => m.SortName)   // sort on SortName
          .Select(m => m.ObjectID)    // select the Id
          .ToList();
```

Comment: I like this idea: instead of doing the comparison on the object's properties, I do the comparison on the output of a function that returns the string I'm sorting on. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Sort on a special property, keep the logic behind it inside your class.

Comment: Quick follow-up: if for some objects in the list the SortName methods ends up returning an empty string, how is the comparison going to work?

Answer (score 1):

If this sorting is specific to one use case, it can be achieved using LINQ:

```
var sortedIds = models.OrderBy(SecondName).Select(m => m.ObjectId).ToList();

private static string SecondName(MyObjectModel model)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(model.LastName)) return model.LastName;
  return model.FirstLastName.Split(' ').Last();
}
```

Comment: Some lastnames have multiple parts (spaces).

Comment: In the case where the name string has multiple parts, I'm comparing on the second string.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use LINQ, as others have suggested, that would involve creating a brand new list, not mutating the existing list.  That may or may not be preferable.  If you want to sort the list itself that's easy enough too:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};

list.Sort((a,b)=> a.CompareTo(b));
```

Just take your list, call `Sort`, and pass in a lambda that takes two items and returns an integer indicating which is greater.  In your case, just call some method on `a` and `b` to get a string and then use `CompareTo` or `string.Compare` on those two strings.